# Open TCP Listener port on windows server 2012, not responding outside of server

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012, tcp

I am trying to set up a simple listener program on my server to listen for requests on a certain port number, e.g. port 1234.

When running, my app starts up and listens on the port number, I can use a browser and get a response of success when I browse to the server IP address and chosen port.

However when I try and browse to this outside of the server I do not get a response.  I am assuming that this is a firewall issue, however I have set up a firewall inbound rule and this has had no affect.

I have run netstat -a -n and my port is showing as listening, with the local address starting 0.0.0.0:1234.

My networking knowledge is very poor, any help?

Comment: You are correct, it is a firewall issue. Re-examine your rules and make sure no additional security programs on the server are blocking it.

Comment: Another thought would be to post a screenshot of the firewall rule or details of what rule you created.

Comment: After speaking with the AWS guys, it seems I needed to add a security group to my instance. Adding this has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with the AWS support team, it seems I needed to add a security group to my instance vm. Adding this has fixed the issue